# What does "&s" do in the API call in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rest

```
const searchMovies=async(title)=>{
    const response =await fetch(`${API_URL}&s=${title}`)
    const data = await response.json();
    setMovies(data.Search)
   }
```

What is `&s` inside the API call? What does it do?

I tried Googling for answers but couldn't find any.

Comment: google for "query-string parameter".

Answer (score 0):

The `&` sign is a separator for query parameters in a URL.
In your sample `s` is a query parameter. But maybe the `API_URL` already contains other query parameters, because before the first parameter usually has to be a `?` sign like in this URL of a google search: `https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=test` where `client` is the first parameter (with the value `firefox-b-d`) and `q` is the second (with the value `test`).

Comment: yes thank you so much, I went and looked at the documentation of that API and it did ask for another parameter "s" which is the search parameter. Sorry for such a lame question haha.

Answer (score 0):

It's part of a query-string which is a component of a universal resource locator ([URL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Common_questions/Web_mechanics/What_is_a_URL)), and it is used to separate multiple queries. See [parameters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Common_questions/Web_mechanics/What_is_a_URL#parameters).

If you want to work with query strings in JS, try the [URLSearchParams](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams) interface, which is part of the web API